# Декорирование вызова функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Извиняюсь за тавтологию заранее.Но в этом примере в строке:

```
log.push([].slice.call(arguments));
```

мы копируем с помощью метода slice  контекст из нескольких аргументов, которые принимает основная функция work в пустой массив,а далее этот новый массив добавляем в массив log  с помощью метода push?

Сам пример:Создайте декоратор makeLogging(func, log), для функции func возвращающий обёртку, которая при каждом вызове добавляет её аргументы в массив log.Допускается func с любым набором аргументов.

```
function work(a, b) {
  alert( a + b ); // work - произвольная функция
}

function makeLogging(f, log) {

  function wrapper() {
      log.push([].slice.call(arguments));
      return f.apply(this, arguments);
    }

  return wrapper;
}

var log = [];
work = makeLogging(work, log);

work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9

for (var i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
  var args = log[i]; // массив из аргументов i-го вызова
  alert( 'Лог:' + args.join() ); // "Лог:1,2", "Лог:4,5"
}
```

Comment: `Мы копируем контекст...` - Нет мы просто копируем сами аргументы, используя метод массива slice для array-like объекта arguments; о контексте тут речь не идёт

Comment: Да,точно вы подметили.. контекст тут даже и не указан.Спасибо вам,что нашли время ответить

Comment: в чем вопрос то?